# C#, EntityFramework - How to access 'Nullable' property of an entity field

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to be able to specify a field name in a specific entity and access its Nullable property.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you show some psuedo-code?

Comment: Have you tried `Field.Value`?

Comment: Improve your question. This is not very clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the property's type is Nullable.

```
var isNullable = 
    theType.IsGenericType && 
    theType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>));
```